# How to view an XML file with a referenced stylesheet on Windows?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file (generated by WCAT load testing tool) that has a referenced XSL file.

But how do I view it? The XML must be transformed by the XSL, but apart from writing some code, is there not a tool that just 'views' XML like this?

**Update**

I have the (expensive) Oxygene installed, but it cannot do the transform due to errors in Microsoft's report.xsl

> Variable rowId has not been declared.
>   Variable state has not been declared.

So this is probably why it failed in IE11, which I thought was supposed to be the standard viewer for XML + XSL on Windows.

Comment: I have corrected the xsl file myself, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36764465/986419

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="{location of the xslt}"?>
```

processing instruction to the xml file before the root element.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I've +1 this because its right and useful, but I wasn't clear. This is already in the XML, I just can't view the final product.

Comment: Does you local machine have access to the "{location of the xslt}"? can you load the "{location of the xslt}" directly into your browser? Might be an location or access issue.

Comment: Yeah its right alongside the XML file, locally, so it should be trusted. There's a Compatibility Mode workaround for IE9, but that's old. There seems to be no way to easily view a transformed XML file on Windows today.